# Vue.js: remember current route inside iframe

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe, single-page-application

I'm having to rebuild a messy legacy web-application (SPA), and found one of the cleanest ways to do it was using Laravel + Vue.js. Due to certain site limitations, the webapp needs to be displayed inside of an iframe.

The iframe points to  the 'entry point' or 'root' of the web-app, and after that, the current page is remembered in PHP with a `$_SESSION['CURRENT_PAGE']` flag and served accordingly, when the user refreshes the page. I would prefer the backend to remain stateless, now that I am transitioning to a cleaner setup with vue.

However: Since the iframe points to `/` of the application, when the user, say, changes to `/hello` and then refreshes the page, it will throw them back to `/`. Is there a standard way of solving this in vue?

An initial guess of mine would be to (ab)use local storage, but maybe that's too crude?

Comment: So the iframe url changes but the browser will still be at `/`, is that correct?

Comment: No the iframe url remains unchanged as of now. But adapting the iframe src url won't do much anyway if you refresh the parent page, right? (Plus I believe Chrome disallows changing the src attribute if I'm not mistaking)

Comment: Without a backend, local storage is one of the few options you have (cookies being another one). I don’t thinks this is an abuse. It is a legitimate use of LocalStorage

Comment: Thanks @RaduDiță, I think I'll use js' localStorage or sessionStorage for that purpose then.